# When did the PC bus start slowing access to video RAM?

Tags: hardware, ibm-pc, memory, video, performance

The PC architecture, from the original IBM PC onward, has always been designed around the idea that video memory will be on an expansion card. This was an unusual design decision; most 80s computers did not do it that way. It has advantages in terms of easier upgrades, but can have the disadvantage of making it slower for the CPU to write to video memory.

Of course nowadays, that doesn't matter because you're not supposed to use the CPU to write to video memory at all; that's the GPU's job. But I'm thinking about the 80s and early 90s, when the CPU still did all the work.

Now, there are always going to be wait states *during active scan line*, because the video chip is using some of the video memory bandwidth for generating the display; that's true regardless of where the video memory is. (Unless you have dual-port VRAM, which was expensive and rarely used.) I'm *not* talking about that here.

I'm talking about wait states incurred by the CPU writing to video memory, even outside active scan line, *because it's on an expansion card at the other end of the expansion bus*, as opposed to main memory on the motherboard.

When did video memory start incurring wait states for that reason? For example, I would expect CGA not to do so because the original IBM PC actually put main memory beyond 64K into expansion cards on the ISA bus. But what about EGA? VGA?

Comment: IBM certainly changed that (only 64KB on the mobo) *really early* in the product’s life.

Comment: @RonJohn sure, but that was rather because working with a 16,,,64 KiB PC wasn't exactly a sales argument :))

Comment: "Unless you have dual-port VRAM, which was expensive and rarely used" - actually, the opposite is true, at least for CGA cards. Admittedly, IBM's original didn't use dual-ported memory, but quite a number of clones did.

Comment: @tofro: I wouldn't particularly expect a CGA clone to use a dual-ported VRAM; since since each video fetch of an even address is always immediately followed by a fetch of the next odd address, page-mode addressing could allow eighty pairs of bytes to be fetched per line with memory timings only slightly tighter than would be needed to perform eighty single accesses (like what would be used in 40-column or graphics mode).

Comment: @supercat Well, even the Amstrad PC1512 had DP-VRAM.

Comment: @tofro: I'm not familiar with that machine.  If it shares main RAM and video RAM, the wait states that would be necessary on the CGA even in 40-column mode would degrade overall program performance compared with what VRAM could offer, but if the memory on a graphics card is only used for CGA-style graphics, the benefits offered by VRAM would be slight.

Comment: @supercat There's no shared memory (that was pretty uncommon in the early days) but rather dedicated video memory. And Amstrad was quite well-known for not overbuilding their machines.

Comment: @tofro: I haven't looked at the design, and I also have never had any information about relative prices of VRAM versus commodity DRAM in different countries.  I remember the price premium for VRAM being significant in the USA, but would not be shocked if it was much lower in the UK.

Comment: @RonJohn That made little difference; memory could be put on PC or PC/AT's expansion bus at no penalty, and within two years of the PC's release multi-peripheral expansion cards such as the [AST SixPakPlus](https://www.minuszerodegrees.net/manuals/AST/Cards/AST%20SixPakPlus%20-%20Users%20Manual%20-%20June%2083.pdf) (which I mention in my answer) made it easy to bring either motherboard up to  at least 544K at essentially no cost in slots.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This question starts with a number of misconceptions about early video,
memory and bus systems that need to be addressed in order to clarify what
this question really appears to be about.

If you want the quick summary, you can skip to the end of this (rather
long, sorry) post.

##### Expansion Cards for Video

> The PC architecture...has always been designed around the idea that video
> memory will be on an expansion card. This was an unusual design
> decision...

Video hardware and memory accessed through an expansion bus were *not* an
unusual design decision; in fact that was how video had commonly been done
before the advent of "all-in-one" units such as the Apple 1 and the
[1977 trinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_personal_computers#1977_and_the_emergence_of_the_%22Trinity%22), on both microcomputer systems and the minicomputers that
preceded them. (And it continued to be done even on systems with built-in
video.) Some examples pre-dating the IBM PC include:

1. The [Knight TV and keyboard](https://github.com/PDP-10/its/wiki/Knight-TV-and-keyboard), dating from somewhere around 1972,
   was a video frame buffer and circuitry on a Unibus expansion card for a
   PDP-11.
2. S-100 machines starting from the Altair, which almost invariably did not
   have built-in video. Video expansion cards for S-100 started appearing
   in 1976. These included the [Cromemco Dazzler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cromemco_Dazzler), which did have onboard
   RAM but accessed system RAM on the bus via DMA. Other cards, such as the
   Processor Technology VDM-1, had onboard RAM. These are actually somewhat
   parallel to the IBM PC CGA and MDA cards, in that the Dazzler was low
   resolution but offered colour graphics, whereas the VDM-1 had higher
   resolution, but offered only monochrome text. You can see quite a few
   more S-100 video boards [in this list](http://dunfield.classiccmp.org/s100c/index.htm).
3. The [JFF Electronics Color Graphics Interface PC Board](http://www.trs-80.org/jff-electronics-color-graphics/), released
   in 1979. This added colour graphics to the TRS-80 Model I and connected
   to its expansion interface connector on the back. I can't find detailed
   technical information on this, but given that it used BASIC `PEEK` and
   `POKE` as well as `OUT` commands, it was almost certainly a memory
   mapped display, with the memory either on the graphics board with the
   CPU accessing it through the expansion bus or it used system RAM with
   the graphics subsystem accessing it through the expansion bus. (There
   were several other graphics expansion cards for the TRS-80 Model I
   introduced from about 1979 onwards as well.)
4. The 8086-based [NEC N5200](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/N5200) (limited English info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APC_series#N5200)),
   released just before the IBM PC in July 1981, had built-in text-only
   video circuitry, but graphics required an expansion board.

For the IBM PC, putting the video cards on the expansion bus was a
perfectly sensible design decision since from the start they were making
two quite different displays available: a high-resolution monochrome
text-only display (MDA) and a slightly lower resolution colour graphics
display (CGA). They could have gone the route of including one of those on
the motherboard and making the other an expansion bus option, as the NEC
N5200 did, but that would then impose extra cost on customers who wanted
the display not built into the motherboard. And, as explained below,
whether the display circuitry was on the motherboard or an expansion card
made no difference.

##### Memory on an Expansion Bus

It is not the case that video memory (or any memory) on an expansion card
will be slower to write than memory on the CPU board. In fact, on most
microcomputers up to and including the IBM PC and PC/AT, using an expansion
interface itself makes *no difference* to memory speed because the
expansion bus is simply an extension of the system bus. Earlier systems,
including all minicomputers and many microcomputers through the mid-1970s
generally had memory *only* on the expansion bus. (E.g., the PDP-11 had
memory, as well as peripherals, on the Unibus, and most S-100 systems, from
the Altair onward up until the single-board systems that started appearing
in the late '70s, had memory on a card separate from the CPU card on the
S-100 bus.)

Even single-board computers often had system RAM on an expansion card,
which was indistinguishable from the RAM on the mainboard except for the
particular location in the address space. The Apple II and II Plus
supported only 48K of RAM on the main board; Apple offered the extremely
popular [Langauge card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_II_Plus#Memory) to add another 16K of RAM, expanding it to 64K.
The TRS-80 Model I as well supported only 16K of RAM on the mainboard;
additional RAM (up to 48K total) was in the [Expansion Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS-80#Model_I_Expansion_Interface).

As with the above machines, the [ISA bus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/473493/15390) used by the IBM PC was just a
(buffered) extension of the system bus and it was normal to put system RAM
on a card on the ISA bus (and, in fact, required if you wanted more than
256K of RAM on the first models). Multi-function expansion cards that
included RAM were very popular; one example was the [AST SixPakPlus](https://www.minuszerodegrees.net/manuals/AST/Cards/AST%20SixPakPlus%20-%20Users%20Manual%20-%20June%2083.pdf) which
included up to 384 KB of RAM, RS-232 serial, a parallel printer port, and a
battery-backed real-time clock.

The key point here is that for many microcomputers, even though the 1980s,
an expansion bus was simply an extension of the system bus, and it made
essentially no difference (for timing or otherwise) whether RAM or other
devices were on a separate card attached to an expansion bus connector or
directly on the motherboard. Electrically and logically, the CPU saw these
as the same.

This did eventually change as PC clones grew faster and yet still wanted to
maintain backward compatibility with older, slower ISA cards. And this is
indeed when wait states started being incurred *"because [the card was] on
an expansion card at the other end of the expansion bus,"* as you ask,
but that had an effect on video memory since it was already incurring wait
states for different reasons we'll get into next.

##### Video RAM Conflicts

> Now, there are always going to be wait states during active scan line,
> because the video chip is using some of the video memory bandwidth for
> generating the display...

This is incorrect.

While it's true that generating a video display from a frame buffer in RAM
will use some of the transfer bandwidth available from the RAM, it is *not*
the case that this always involves delaying CPU access or making the CPU
wait, even with single-ported memory. That depends entirely on the system
design and the speed of the RAM.

A fair number of systems (particularly 6800- and 6502-based ones) used RAM
considerably faster than necessary for just the CPU, allowing them not to
delay CPU memory accesses at all. This is easy on Motorola bus systems
(6800/6502/6809/etc.) because the CPU accesses memory only on one phase of
the clock cycle, known as ϕ0 or ϕ2. This leaves memory entirely free for
access on the other phase, ϕ1 and, if the memory is fast enough, it can be
read by the video subsystem during this time at no penalty to CPU access
speed. The Apple II and the BBC Micro are among the classic examples of
this technique¹, but it was very widely used elsewhere.

Unfortunately for Intel bus systems, such as the 8080, Z80, and 8088,
things become a bit more complex. While on a typical 1 MHz Motorola bus
system the regular ϕ2 500 ns CPU access cycle followed by ϕ1 500 ns free
cycle allows for regular and synchronous access to RAM when the CPU is not
accessing it, and the typical 250 ns access time of mid- to late-'70s DRAM
provides plenty of RAM bandwidth to read or write data in each of these two
cycles, Intel bus systems have a more asynchronous access pattern.

On Intel bus systems the CPU is typically run with a 2-4 MHz clock where [a
varying number of these "T-states"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z80#Instruction_execution) (4-10 on the 8080, and up to
23 on some compatible CPUs) are required to execute a single instruction,
and memory will be accessed during certain T-states of certain "M-cycles"
which consist of 3-6 adjacent T-states. (The complexity is increased even
further if the Z80 CPU's support for DRAM refresh is used, as that will
access memory during some groups of T-states where the CPU instruction/data
fetch unit does not access memory.)

Thus, it's typical on Intel bus systems to avoid entirely the difficult
problem of figuring out on which cycles the CPU is accessing memory and
simply request that the CPU pause during the times when an external system
needs to access memory for any reason.² (This is referred to as "direct
memory access" or [DMA](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12569/7208).)

This technique was used from quite early on because it allows for
completely asynchronous access by the DMA system, whether it be for a video
display or other purposes. For example, the [NEC TK-80](https://gitlab.com/retroabandon/tk80-re) trainer board used
DMA to read eight memory addresses from RAM to provide the data for which
segments to light in its eight 7-segement LED displays; the circuit that
did the DMA was run by a simple 555 timer that had no synchronisation with
the system clock (and, taking its timing from an R/C network rather than a
crystal resonator, did not even have exact or perfectly steady timing).

And this, as explained in [supercat's answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/29650/7208), is how the CGA
card deals with memory access conflicts: it simply pauses the CPU while
it's reading from video memory. Note that this has *nothing* to do with the
expansion bus on most microcomputers through the IBM PC and PC/AT; the same
issue would exist if the CGA video subsystem were built into the
motherboard (and indeed does exist on PC clones with built-in CGA, such as
the early Compaq portables).

Nor is it even required to deal with these memory access conflicts via wait
states or any other means. One obviously doesn't want to skip memory writes
to VRAM from the CPU, as then it would be instructing things to appear on
the screen that would not appear, but it's perfectly reasonable to simply
skip *reads* by the video subsystem if they would interfere with writes to
(or reads from) VRAM by the CPU. This will simply introduce blanks (or,
more usually, rubbish) on the screen when the video system is prevented
from reading VRAM. And this was far from unknown; among the many systems
that did this was the TRS-80 Model I (where the video memory and display
subsystem were on the motherboard), which would display "static" on the
screen when video subsystem reads were preempted by CPU reads or writes.

It's also worth mentioning that, from the introduction of microcomputers,
wait states were often introduced simply because [memory or another
peripheral was slow](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/29659/7208). This had nothing to do with it being on
an expansion bus or not; as with the video examples above, it was part of
the nature of accessing the chips themselves, regardless of how connected
to the CPU.

##### GPUs and Modern Systems

The CPU/GPU split is not new: in the microcomputer world it's existed since
at least 1979 when the Texas Instruments [TMS9918 Video Display
Processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMS9918) was released. The 9918 had its own separate video RAM
(accessed via sending read and write commands to the chip) and, as well as
having an extremely flexible character or glyph display system, also could
do certain things on its own, such as display sprites.

This might not be considered a "true" GPU since it didn't actually ever
write to its on video RAM (in the initial versions, anyway), but the
following year's NEC [μPD7220](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEC_%CE%BCPD7220) High-Performance Graphics Display Controller
(one of the best known graphics chips of the 1980s amongst those who were
familiar with the market) did have commands to instruct it to do things
like write lines and sectors of circles to the frame buffer, just as GPUs
do today (except in a much more sophisticated way). Nor was this restricted
to custom silicon: The 1981 Fujitsu FM-8 (and FM-7, FM77 and subsequent
machines in the series) used a second 6809 CPU with its own address space
and graphics code to draw characters and graphics on its 640×200 bitmap
display. (The video subsystem itself had no character display
functionality; the graphics CPU always had to write the individual dots of
each character.)

Modern systems using a GPU still have the exact same issues with having to
wait to write to memory, except perhaps worse. CPUs and GPUs communicate
mostly through shared memory (either the system RAM or RAM on the GPU card
that is usually called "VRAM"), with the CPU writing instructions and data
for the GPU into system RAM or VRAM and the GPU reading those, updating the
data where necessary, and then writing what is to be displayed to the frame
buffer for the video subsystem to read. (The frame buffer is in VRAM, but
is only a very small part of it. A 4K full-colour frame buffer is only
about 32 MB, a small fraction of the gigabytes of VRAM on modern GPU
cards. The majority of the data in VRAM is usually "textures," of which the
GPU reads only a small part for every frame in order to produce modified
data to be written to the frame buffer.)

Effectively, this is introducing a separate computer between the "main"
computer and the video subsystem. So what we now have to deal with is,
unlike a frame buffer, a very strict requirement that neither the CPU nor
the GPU can fail a read or write to their shared memory. Thus when both
want to read or write at the same time, one or the other *must* wait.
Again, this is nothing to do with the bus, but inherent to the nature of
shared memory.

##### Summary

1. The IBM PC putting video memory or a video subsystem on an expansion
   card was not an unusual idea; it was very common long before the IBM PC
   came out.
2. Putting the video memory/video subsystem on a card did not make it
   slower for the IBM PC to access video memory. That was inherent in the
   nature of the memory and video subsystem itself. Or more precisely, it
   was because IBM chose to prioritise a clean (i.e., never showing
   "static") display over the speed at which the CPU could write (or read)
   RAM used as a video frame buffer.
3. The wait states for PC video memory in CGA and MDa cards (and for many,
   many things—memory and non-memory alike—before it) were not added by the
   bus, but by the device itself. On the PC and PC/AT (and the vast
   majority of other microcomputers up to that time) whether the device was
   on an expansion bus or on the motherboard made no difference to wait
   states.
4. Multiple device access to VRAM still does matter today: even when using
   a GPU we still share memory between the GPU and the CPU and between the
   GPU and the video display subsystem that reads the frame buffer, and all
   the same issues apply if not using dual-ported RAM.
5. From the question in the final two paragraphs in your post, it appears
   that what you are interested in has nothing to do with video or even
   shared RAM, but is merely about expansion buses. Introducing video and
   RAM into this simply obscures your question (or what I believe *should*
   be your question).

To answer that final question, PC expansion buses *themselves* started
slowing access to devices on expansion cards (whether video RAM or anything
else) somewhere between about 1984 and 1987.

- The latter date is when IBM introduced [Micro Channel architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Channel_architecture)
  was introduced, and MCA was the first PC bus designed from the start to
  run at a different speed from the CPU.
- However, PC clone vendors making systems that were faster than the IBM PC
  or PC/AT were seeing issues with expansion cards failing due to too-fast
  access several years before that. (The problems were generally not with
  VRAM, which was already slowing access on its own, but with other devices
  that just assumed the PC bus wouldn't be run faster than 4.77 MHz or the
  PC/AT bus wouldn't be run faster than 8 MHz.)
- At some point the chipset vendors introduced the ability to run the ISA
  bus at a different rate from the CPU, and the first one of those would
  have been exactly when *expansion buses* started introducing wait states.

---

<sup>¹ The Apple II did [introduce a very small delay](https://archive.org/details/the-apple-ii-circuit-description_20210925/page/30/mode/1up) (139 ns, or
1/7 of a CPU clock cycle) for each horizontal scan line. This was entirely
unnecessary as far as memory speed is concerned, but was introduced in
order to avoid alternating lines having a 180° phase difference in the
colour carrier, which simplfies the colour hardware for reasons I won't get
into here.</sup>

<sup>² It is possible to get "pseudo-synchronous" access to the memory to
do DMA on 8080 (but probably not Z80) systems: the first M-cycle of every
instruction consists of five T-cycles where the first three are used to
fetch the instruction and the final two are used for instruction decode,
leaving the memory free. It's possible, with a non-trivial amount of logic,
to access the memory during T4 and/or T5; the Altair 88-S4K 4k Dynamic RAM
board [used this technique for dynamic RAM referesh](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/29656/7208). However,
with this technique the memory bandwith is limited to two T-states per
instruction, with the worst case being a sequence of `DAD` instructions (10
T-cycles each) giving a worst-case memory bandwith of 1 to 2 accesses every
10 T-clocks, perhaps 200,000 bytes per second (depending heavily on CPU and
memory speed). That's a little over 3 KB per frame for a standard video
system, which is enough to read data for a text screen (assuming that each
character is read only once per frame—which has its own issues), but
obviously not enough for, e.g., 320×200 monochrome graphics which requires
reading 8000 bytes of memory per frame.</sup>

Comment: If the Apple II hadn't added the extra 1/2 chroma cycle on every line, even scan lines would have had the opposite color phase from odd ones, which would have been the way NTSC video was designed to work.  Showing hires blue would have required a checkerboard rather than a vertical stripe pattern, and orange would have required the opposite checkerboard, but that would probably have improved visual quality for programs that were designed to work that way.

Comment: @supercat Good point. But you're talking about hi-res graphics only; consider what happens to lo-res graphics with an alternating phase, and how that would have to be fixed. (I have tweaked my answer based on this, though.)

Comment: "never showing "static" - CGA did this all the time didn't it?  I have a memory of yellow text on a monochrome VDU 'shivvering' whenever I pressed return.

Comment: @Neil Actually, that was my understanding from supercat's answer (which I may have misread); David G.'s answer seems to disagree with this. (My original IBM PC was an MDA system; I have little personal experience with colour systems.)

Comment: Perhaps @supercat can clarify the purpose and effect of the wait states he mentions in his answer.

Comment: About the original IBM PC video adapters I’ll add one observation: not only it would have made no difference performance-wise but, honestly, it would not have fit even if they had wanted to. The 5150 motherboard was quite busy already, and the CGA and MDA boards are also very large (both full-length) as they all rely heavily on off-the-shelf low integration chips.

Comment: @cjs On original CGA CPU access has priority access to memory. FF in U2 visible in the top left quadrant of sheet 4 of the schematics (p. D-28 in the 1981 TechRef) locks he CPU address multiplexers and disables the 6845 (s.1). Thus the character latch (s.2) will store whatever the CPU reads or writes during that cycle. in result a random value is read which in turn is suppressed, giving a white line in graphics mode or a white square in character mode - much like a cursor square. To avoid this the BIOS always waited for a retrace before outputting a character. The reason why it was so slow.

Comment: @cjs BTW, this only happened in 80 col or highres graphics modes, as in 40 col mode there's enough time to satisfy CPU and video.

Comment: @Raffzahn: The High Resolution and Medium Resolution graphics modes only fetch 40 byte pairs per line, just like 40-column text mode, and thus do not require a retrace wait.  Although the Low Resolution mode (160x100 16 colors) is only half the resolution of hires, it needs to fetch 80 byte pairs per line, and is thus has the same snow-free timing limitations as 80-column mode.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Is there an effort to stifle display output when the CPU grabs a cycle?  Forcing attribute memory to behave as though it fetched the value in the port-3D9 latch (replicated in both nybbles) would have visually reduced the visual effect of snow, but from what I remember the display would behave as though the value being written was fetched as an attribute, with no attempt being made to stifle the fetch.  Or would the display fetch the correct character and wrong attribute but blank the character in a manner that made things worse than they otherwise would have been?

Comment: @supercat Looking at the schematics it seems as if it would have been easy to blank the pixels/character (use background value) during CPU access. at maximum one additional TTL (if not doable by wired or or spare gates). They might have simply not seen the necessary. After all, even with only writing off field text comes faster than one can read :))

Comment: @Raffzahn: You say "a random value is read, which in turn is suppressed".  Is there circuitry which suppresses the character value or its serialized output?  That suggests that circuitry existed which could have mitigated snow, but it was wrongly applied.  The CGA feels as though different people designed different aspects, and some coordination could have yielded a more useful product with less circuitry.  For example, replacing the graphics color-control circuitry with a 4x4 register file (same chip as is used for DMA banking selection on the motherboard) would make it easy...

Comment: ...to have the highlighted portion of the cursor behave as though its attribute differed from the rest of the character, and would have provided a spot for the programmer to put the attribute that should be used on any colliding video fetch.

Answer (score 15):

### TL;DR: When the CPU-bus became faster than the I/O-bus

> Now, there are always going to be wait states during active scan line, because the video chip is using some of the video memory bandwidth for generating the display

Not really; there are many ways to make that transparent. Starting with the VDU not needing the whole bandwidth during scan line.

> Unless you have dual-port VRAM, which was expensive and rarely used.

Not needed. Already a 1-transaction (one byte or word) write buffer can level the playing field. This is possible as

- reads are rare, so having them blocking doesn't hinder much;
- the VDU may not need all bandwidth, so a single postponed write may be injected;
- the CPU does usually not access video as a burst but single byte/word access.

The last is especially relevant, as an access loop may contain a dozen or more instructions with many memory cycles but only one of them being an I/O write cycle.

> I'm talking about wait states incurred by the CPU writing to video memory, even outside active scan line, because it's on an expansion card at the other end of the expansion bus, as opposed to main memory on the motherboard.

It helps to remember that on the PC (and XT) the I/O-bus was clocked at the same rate as main memory. There was no general penalty for accessing. Same speed, same performance.

> When did video memory start incurring wait states for that reason?

Generic wait states only became a thing when the CPUs were faster clocked than the I/O-bus. And that was a general slowdown, not just for video cards.

> For example, I would expect CGA not to do so because the original IBM PC actually put main memory beyond 64K into expansion cards on the ISA bus. But what about EGA? VGA?

Neither of them, as it was about the different clock speed for either bus domain. On a 4.77 MHz PC or XT with 4.77 MHz I/O-bus no wait states were added. Same on a 10 MHz 386 with ISA bus clocked up to 10 MHz (*1). On the other side, already an 9.54 Mhz 8088 will have to wait if ISA is clocked at 4.77.

---

*1- Back in the days of ISA graphic cards we invested many hours (and money) to select cards that could run as high as possible, so we could crank up ISA bus speed :))

Comment: According to the benchmark utility I used at the time, the fastest unaccelerated VGA card I ever used was a Trident in a '486 DX33 with the ISA bus clocked up to whatever the BIOS would let me.

Comment: @Neil Those were the days :))

Answer (score 11):

The original CGA always imposed wait states on display memory accesses.  The card's memory subsystem always performs one access every four pixel clocks, and only half of those are available to the CPU regardless of whether the display is enabled or what mode it's in.  Although the pixel clock and CPU clock happen to both be generated off of a 14.3818MHz time source, the CPU clock and display-memory clock are asynchronous (the card has no way of knowing that the CPU clock is derived from that source).  Any CPU read or write request must be delayed until a following 1.7977MHz timing window, and not even necessarily the immediately following one, since a request that occurs near the end of a window will miss the next window and have to wait for the one after that.  If memory serves, CGA display memory accesses have something around 4-6 wait states on a stock 4.77MHz PC, and more wait states on faster machines.

Note that these wait states are not sufficient to allow clean updates in 80-column text mode.  During the active portion of each 80-column line, memory fetches alternate between those where display hardware owns the bus and the CPU can't have it, and those where display hardware needs to fetch display data but will let the CPU have the bus anyway.  If the CPU attempts to access display memory at those times, a transient visual glitch will appear wherever the beam happened to be at that moment.

Comment: The CGA card used the 14.31818 MHz clock from the motherboad. It did not have a crystal onboard. So they used the same clock from the same crystal and thus were synchronous with the 4.77 MHz CPU which used the crystal divided by 3.

Comment: @Justme: The CGA card was intended to be (and was) compatible with motherboards whose CPU clock was not derived from that 14.3818Mhz clock.

Comment: @Justme: Do you like the new wording?

Comment: I think so. On later machines the bus might run at CPU based rate, so the reads and writes can be asynchronous, and it will work as long as the bus has enough wait states at CPU rate so the bus cycles are not too fast for the peripheral.

Comment: @Justme: The CGA will add its own wait states whether or not the motherboard would add any otherwise.

Comment: I used my first (clone) PC with a TV as monitor, taking composite video from the CGA to an external RF modulator.  I was only able to get B&W images, however, and this puzzled me for a while until I discovered the 14.31818MHz clock on the motherboard was slightly off.  This clock is divided by 4 to generate the 3.579545 color burst on the composite video.  I added a trimmer cap on the motherboard crystal, tweaked the 14MHz oscillator, and finally got color.

Comment: I think you might be thinking of the original VGA.  The CGA did the waits in software.  See my answer.

Comment: @DavidG.: The CGA alternates memory cycles between those that are available to the CPU and those that aren't.  In 80-column text mode, all cycles are used for fetching display data when available, but the CPU can override display fetches on half of them (producing snow).

Comment: Are you saying the cycles were available in 40 column mode?  Aren't the memory bandwidth requirements the same for all 3 graphics mode, and 80 column text, and only lower for 40 column text?  I suspect the "visual glitch" in medium & high res graphics was black.  (I will admit to not remembering all the register settings, and never worked out the glitch in the schematics.  Or even all the negative vs positive logic.)

Comment: @DavidG.: Only 80-column text and "Low Resolution Graphics" [which is actually an 80x100 text mode] need 160 bytes per scan line.  All other modes use 80 bytes per scan line, which may be 40 character+attribute pairs, 16 High Resolution pixels, or eight Medium Resolution pixels.

Comment: oh, right, forgot the color byte...  which actually may explain the snow: the color is what's messed up, coming out as white on white (probably the negative logic...).   Note that "Low Resolution Graphics" is 160x100, since one fills the characters with a half-on-half-off character and turn off blink.  It would not surprise me if the 40 column text mode has issues too, in that instead of being use/idle/... it may be use/use/idle/idle/...  This could just cause a longer delay, but probably doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, if you carefully read the BIOS for the IBM PC and CGA video (I did), you will find that (at least in text mode) it delayed every access to the video memory until the display entered a horizontal retrace.  This was because, if you accessed the bus while things were being displayed, a little fleck of white appeared on the screen.

If you, like me, type in the BIOS source, remove the delays, and rebuild;
then suddenly the video access gets to be a whole lot faster.  Of course, you would get the little white snow all over the place.  (My TSR also gave me a 100 line scrollback.  :-) )

I suspect (but can't prove) that IBM could have added a gate or two to make the flecks black, and thus much less noticeable.  Of course, IBM was doing everything they could to reduce the chip/gate count.

In short, it isn't necessarily the bus that is slowing access to video RAM.

Comment: I don't think that black snow would be necessarily less noticeable - it would just affect different parts of the display (text rather than the background; or everywhere in full-screen applications that use a non-black background).  Mid-grey might be a better choice, since it's equally far from all extremes.

Comment: @TobySpeight I think that black snow would be less noticeable because of the mechanics of vision (though again I can't prove it).  Grey would still show up on a  black background.

Comment: Yes, that's a fair point.  There's an argument for one side or the other (I'm not sure which) in that the reason that PAL signals have zero as white and maximum level as black is something to do with noise perception.  We're more sensitive to differences in dark colours than in bright ones.  So black is more noticeable against a dark background than white is against a bright background.  But I'm no colour-perception expert, so my input must end there.

Comment: Removing retrace delays will make display updates faster, but still not as fast as writes to conventional memory.  I see I forgot to mention the significance of 80-column mode in my answer, which I'll fix.

Answer (score 0):

In many ways it's not that the PC architecture has slow access to video RAM. It's that, thanks to a lack of advanced features like sprites and backgrounds, it requires much more access to video RAM.  Namely it has to go out and write to a framebuffer for anything that can't be handled as text.